# How to determine which variable is incorrect using Catch fuction?

Tags: powershell

Currently I am experimenting with the Catch function in PowerShell, to imporve my skillset. 
I have a decent start, I know how to error check with one variable but how do I do this using Catch with two?

```
"7" {
    $source = Read-Host "Enter AD account you want to copy from"
    $dist = Read-Host " Enter AD account to be assigned same groups"
Try {
    get-aduser -Identity $source -properties memberof | select-object memberof -ExpandProperty memberof | Add-ADGroupMember -members $dist

}
Catch {
    throw "No user found in AD with SamAccountName '$source'"
}
```

Comment: if you need to track errors for more  than one cmdlet, you can ... [A] use  the `$_` in the `catch` block to see the error that triggered the catch ... or [B] wrap each cmdlet in it's own `try/catch`. ///// there are likely others, too. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-ErrorVariable` parameter to achieve what you want.

If I take your example and update it, you could do the following:

```
Try {
    get-aduser -Identity $source -properties memberof -ErrorVariable errorsFromGetADUser | select-object memberof -ExpandProperty memberof | Add-ADGroupMember -members $dist -ErrorVariable errorsFromAddADGroupMember
}
Catch {
    if ($errorsFromGetADUser) {
        # We failed while trying to get the user
    }
    else if ($errorsFromAddADGroupMember) {
        # We successfully retrieved the user
    }
}
```